# What do we do about vague music ID requests?

Tags: discussion, policies

so with this question [What is the song near the end of Episode 24? (Akame ga Kill)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/36559/1587) how it describes when the song occurs is kinda vague. we don't know when someone considers an anime episode having reached the end in where they can observe a scene, is it 5 minutes before the ED? 3 minutes? the scene after the ED?

To avoid acting too late what do we do about these Vague Music Requests?

Answer (score 11):

I suggest the following:

When posting a Music Identification Request you should expect to see the series name indicated by the paired tag with [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and/or in the question and a description of an identifiable scene that the music occurs. ie

> what is the music that plays in Sword Art Online when everyone is gathered in the town of beginning learning that Kayaba has prevented them for logging out

things which can also narrow the scene down are

- an episode number
- a timestamp
- a link to a legal video source (some leeway given to youtube videos)

the first 2 points above can replace a scene description when used together. the last point should always come with a scene description even if the first 2 points are given because if the link dies the timestamp may become invalid, especially if the OP/ED/Transition Scenes/etc are removed (remember that OP and ED's combined are ~3 minutes).

## If the request is vague...

request clarification and have the OP edit the question. if nothing happens (say within 24 hours but how long you wait is up to you) Vote to Close as **Unclear**.

maybe also leave a comment saying that the question can be re-opened if clarification is edited in, this will then put the closed question in the Review Que for reopen votes.

In essence from the description you should know or be able to believe that the described scene can be referenced with a timestamp if one isn't given.

using the link in this question that would be closed as unclear as the scene is described to be *"near the end of the episode"* and at what time would one consider near the end?

Comment: I think there always has to be a timestamp, no matter what source (legal tv episode, dvd or a pirate streaming site).

Comment: I agree with @Hakase. Really, I can't think of any reason that anybody should have difficulty including an episode number and timestamp (for precision) AND a description of the scene where the music plays (in case of time-shifting because of ads, sponsor messages, etc). Hakase - I notice you've been policing these questions fairly aggressively lately. Thanks for that; I'll try to keep on top of them too.

Comment: @senshin I've just been noticing them, that's all :p Besides it's basic search logic to look through soundtrack listings and anime lyrics sites. Maybe we should have a guide for music ID, just like for anime ID.

Comment: @senshin one legitimate reason i can think of that an asker may not include a timestamp is if they saw it in a format they can't review such as on TV or in the Cinema.

Comment: @Memor-X D'oh. I genuinely forgot that people watch TV! You're right, that's a legitimate reason.

Comment: @Hakase well there can be the situation where the asker posts a small segment or highlight of an episode, said video may only be a few minutes long and it's timestamp probably wont match to the full episode. though if the user does post a full episode then yeh maybe then we can expect a timestamp aswell

Comment: Sure, if it's a cut of only the relevant fragment, it's fine not to add a timestamp, but in a general case we're usually talking about a whole episode.

Comment: youtube videos of minutely small segments of episodes can fall under [fair use.](https://www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/fair-use.html#yt-copyright-four-factors) - IANAL, but you don't see Hasbro suing people for posting those 3 second pony videos. For the music identification, probably only few seconds would suffice to point where it begins.

Comment: It'd be helpful if there was a button on the review queue that read something like "Extra detail needed", sometimes a question with merit needs touching up, but No Action Needed and VTC are quite opposite ends of the spectrum. I know there is the edit button, but a lot of the time the reviewer doesn't have the appropriate knowledge, perhaps a request edit button would be helpful. Not just for these music questions but in general.

Answer (score 4):

One other thing to help with the search is to ask OP to add screenshot of the scene when the music starts, like in this question:

[What is the song at 07:37 in episode 60 of Naruto?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36896/naruto-ost-episode-60)