# How to ask a music identification question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was watching an anime, and this really awesome piece of music came on. I want to know what it's called, but I don't know where to start looking. I know I can ask for help here on Anime.SE, but how should I do it? What information should I provide?

Comment: Related [What do we do about vague music ID requests?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3936/1587)

Answer (score 14):

I'm glad you asked, person who is totally not me!

There are really only a few pieces of information that are essential when you're trying to have a piece of music from an anime identified. Namely:

- The **name** of the anime. (Obviously.)
- If you watched the anime dubbed (i.e. the dialogue was not in Japanese), indicate **what language it was in**.
- A description of at least one time when the music you're looking for was played, meaning:

  - If it's something that has multiple episodes, the **episode number**.
  - A **description in words** of what is happening on-screen when the music plays.
  - If at all possible, you should provide a **timestamp**.
    (That said, if you're looking for a song from, say, a movie you only saw in theaters, we understand that you can't reasonably come up with a timestamp for that.)

That's it! You can even fit it all into one sentence: "What is the song that plays 6 minutes into episode 134 of *Naruto*, at the beginning of Naruto's fight with Sasuke?" (I don't know anything about *Naruto*; this example is purely hypothetical.)

---

In some cases, additional information may help people find you an answer more quickly. For example:

- If it's a vocal song, mention that. If you can tell what language it's in, mention that, too. (If you understand the lyrics, though, just go google them.)
- Have you noticed that this song pretty much always plays when a character shows up on screen? Some songs are really easy to identify if you mention that it's so-and-so's motif.
- Is the musical style distinctive, like a jazz piece in a soundtrack that's mostly electronic? That can definitely help people narrow it down faster.
- If you can list off multiple instances where the song was played, that may be helpful.
- If you're particularly enterprising, consider including a short extract (10-15 seconds, say) of the audio you're talking about - this way, someone who's familiar with the soundtrack might be able to answer your question right away! I personally like http://clyp.it as a place to upload audio, but anything works, really.

Comment: Also, sometimes useful or even important: whether the music is from the original Japanese version, or any other dubs because we know that dubs tend to replace it with their [own](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30192/who-is-the-artist-for-mistys-goodbye-song-during-the-flashback-at-gotta-catch) [song](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40473/who-did-the-spinning-wheel-song-in-the-english-dub-of-the-garo-season-1-ova)

Comment: @AkiTanaka A very good point! I always make the assumption that people are talking about the original Japanese version, but if someone is referring to some other version, it's very important to mention that. I added that to the list of "essential" pieces of information.